# queue.get() with a cumulative timeout for n elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, buffer

The [`queue.Queue.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get) method has a `timeout` parameter to wait for the presence of one element to retrieve.

I would like to retrieve "at most" 25 elements "at once", waiting "at most" 5 seconds. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I removed the `python-trio` tag, as it is not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply calculate the remaining time(out).

```
TIMEOUT=5

t = time.monotonic()+TIMEOUT
items = []
for n in range(25):
    try:
        items.append(q.get(timeout=t-time.monotonic()))
    except queue.Empty:
        break
```